# Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: 7, database

I am keep getting this annoying response from PDO. The error is quite self-explanatory, however the solution (setting `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`) doesn't work for me.

`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` is already enabled in `database.inc` as suggested. Also Drupal get stuck on much early stage if I change the value to false, so I am assuming that this setting is effective most of the time but not always (which is weird).

The project is quite big and I am not the original developer, so it's not possible to inspect hundreds of files and fix every custom query or add `$db->closeCursor()` to them.

What would be your suggestion in this case?

The exact error message is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.